# Identify if an element is GPU accelerated using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, gpu, hardware-acceleration

We're working on a project that executes user written code similar to jsfiddle.net but we've run into issues where a few users are GPU accelerating a large number of elements and creating poor browser experiences for themselves and occasionally crashing the page, leading to a large number of complaints from a few alpha users. We are looking for a real-time method in JavaScript within the browser, without the use of dev tools, by which to ascertain which elements are accelerated, thus knowing the count and fire a warning once they've reached a limit. My research so far has not returned any useful results and I was hoping SO could help. Thanks ahead of time!